# VirtualHost add sub domain?

Tags: web-hosting, apache, web-development, webserver, centos

I rarely touch apache configs but I must be doing something wrong here.

trying to set it up so these domains point to different webroots:

example.com -> var/www/html

ggurt.example.com -> var/www/html/ggurt

With the current config (screenshot below), ggurt.example.com and example.com BOTH go to var/www/html/ggurt. I want the sub domain and second level domain to have different webroots. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I give examples in my answer in the link above that should help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

There's lot's more on Apache configuration over at StackOverflow. Like you I've done very little in the config files, so apologies if this is not much use.

Not entirely sure this answers your question, but worth a punt: [httpd Virtualhost Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343546/httpd-virtualhost-subdomains)